# JDOM to objects list

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have a problem with reading data from `String`. This string looks like xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AAA container="main">
    <BBB cont = "firstB">
        <CCC>
            <value1>something</value1>
            <value2>something<value2>
        </CCC>
        <CCC>
            <value1>something</value1>
            <value2>something<value2>
        </CCC>
    </BBB>
    <BBB cont = "secondB">
        <CCC>
            <value1>something</value1>
            <value2>something<value2>
        </CCC>
    </BBB>
</AAA>
```

I created two classes for CCC and BBB objects:

```
class MyCCC{
   String value1;
   String value2;
};

class MyBBB{
   String cont;
   List<MyCCC> ccc;
}
```

How is it possible to get List of BBB elements?

Comment: his is possible, but you probably want to use some kind of bean library. There is a number to choose from, eg Spring, apache xmlbeans, ... The question is a bit broad though

Answer (score 0):

The input string doesn't look like XML, it **is** XML. It would seem you are trying to parse the input into objects. Rather than using JDOM and doing the conversion from Document Object Model to your own object structure manually, I suggest you look into [JAXB (the Java Architecture for XML Binding)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Architecture_for_XML_Binding), which will do exactly that. It can read XML input and create objects from it, and conversely take objects and turn them into XML output. You will find [a tutorial here](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/). The JAXB API has been part of the Java SE API for a while now, and you can find the classes in [package javax.xml.bind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/package-summary.html).